# How can I get an Email when my APIs goes down?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a few APIs written in NodeJs using Express, Which are hosted on AWS EC2, What can I do to get an email whenever my APIs go down? Can I use any service of AWS like CloudWatch to send an Email when my API crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using CloudWatch's [synthetic monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html) to:

> create canaries, configurable scripts that run on a schedule, to monitor your endpoints and APIs. Canaries follow the same routes and perform the same actions as a customer, which makes it possible for you to continually verify your customer experience even when you don't have any customer traffic on your applications. By using canaries, you can discover issues before your customers do.

You can [monitor canary events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitoring-events-eventbridge.html) with EventBridge and send custom notifications, including email.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a beginner, but isn't SNS the solution you would want for this situation?

Comment: The key thing is here is how to actually monitor your application on AWS to know when it's responding slower than usual or is actually not responding to users. Detecting those operational issues then allows you to send notifications, which you would do via SNS. So SNS is part of the solution, but it's not the solution.